# Correct way to implement Http API method for exporting data to file

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm implementing an API method that allows for exporting some data to a file. The format of the file is selected by the caller of the method.
The API method currently has an URI-form like so: `/customers/{customerId}/shoppingchart/export/{fileTypeId}` but what is the "correct" Http-way, if any, to implement the file type selection? Should the choice be specified by the Http Accept header or in the URI or some other way? And, what is the correct status to return if the asked format isn't supported?

Comment: Does the API request return the file, or does it just create the file?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It returns the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the HTTP Accept header to specify the file type.

[RFC 2616 states](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.

However this does not indicate whether you can create your own custom types (should you wish that).

[The HTTProtocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3) describes an Accept header as this:

> This field contains a semicolon-separated list of representation schemes ([Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Object_Headers.html#z16) metainformation values) which will be accepted in the response to this request.

The above link then points to the definition of a Content-Type exactly. What's important here is

> The `x-` convention for experimental types is of course still available as well.

This tells us that we can define our own custom types in an Accept header given that we prepend them with `x-` (e.g. `x-ext` for `.ext` files)  as is common in the HTTProtocol.

> What is the correct status to return if the asked format isn't supported?

I would argue **HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type** as defined in section [10.4.16](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is appropriate here.

> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.